# Beautiful Soup: searching for a nested pattern?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

`soup.find_all` will search a BeautifulSoup document for all occurrences of a single tag.  Is there a way to search for particular patterns of nested tags?

For example, I would like to search for all occurrences of this pattern:

```
<div class="separator">
  <a>
    <img />
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to find the pattern, but the easiest one would be to use a [`CSS selector`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors):

```
for img in soup.select('div.separator > a > img'):
    print img  # or img.parent.parent to get the "div"
```

Demo:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> data = """
... <div>
...     <div class="separator">
...       <a>
...         <img src="test1"/>
...       </a>
...     </div>
... 
...     <div class="separator">
...       <a>
...         <img src="test2"/>
...       </a>
...     </div>
... 
...     <div>test3</div>
... 
...     <div>
...         <a>test4</a>
...     </div>
... </div>
... """
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
>>> 
>>> for img in soup.select('div.separator > a > img'):
...     print img.get('src')
... 
test1
test2
```

I do understand that, strictly speaking, the solution would not work if the `div` has more than just one `a` child, or inside the `a` tag there is smth else except the `img` tag. If this is the case the solution can be improved with additional checks (will edit the answer if needed).

Comment: This is perfect, thanks!  In my particular application I'll be using img.parent to modify the enclosing <a>.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this part of the [docs](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-function). You probably want a  function like this:

```
def nested_img(div):
    child = div.contents[0]
    return child.name == "a" and child.contents[0].name == "img"

soup.find_all("div", nested_img)
```

P.S.: This is untested.